# atof reads string as 0

Tags: c, atof

I suppose I am just stupid (I tried all). Help me out of here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    const char * y = "747.0";
    double x;
    x = atof(y);
    printf("%.5f\n",x);
    printf("%e\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
0.00000
0.000000e+00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include `stdlib.h` to offer `atof()` a prototype, without proper prototype, compiler will suppose its return value be an `int`.

Comment: that's why it's recommended to turn on all warnings

Answer (score 0):

Try including stdlib.h because I think that is the package you need for atoi in C.